I can't install reactivision because libdc1394-22 is not installable
I tried downloading and installing reactivision_1.5.1-1_amd64.deb on my Lubuntu 24.04.1 LTS, but I get the following error :
"The following packages have unmet dependencies:
reactivision: Dépend: libdc1394-22 but it is not installable"
So I tried to install libdc1394-22 manually, but it didn't worked. I read that it was replaced by libdc1394.
I checked with
ldconfig -p | grep libdc1394

And I got
libdc1394.so.25 (libc6,x86-64) => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdc1394.so.25

so I think its installed.
But I still can't install reactivision…
Thanks for your help, I'm quite lost here
EDIT : I followed Install old library file required by a program and created a symlink to libdc1394.so.25 and so far it worked

You've provided no clues as to what that deb file you're trying to install is, where its from, OR critically what it was packaged for... Some quick checks online and it appears (and I could be looking at different file details as you gave none!) how it was packaged well over a decade ago thus I'd expect package problems.. but even if you got it installed; I'd fear segfault or ABI/API breakage which is what the package problems are preventing. Giving some specifics about your file maybe helpful.

Thanks for your reply. I found the deb here : https://reactivision.sourceforge.net/ It's the reactivision_1.5.1-1_amd64.deb package.
